# Solve won't find solution to simultaneous matrix equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a pair of simultaneous matrix equations of the form,

$$AX + XA^\dagger + BJB^\dagger = 0,\ \ X C^\dagger + B J D^\dagger = 0,$$
where,
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

However sometimes Mathematica cannot find a solution:

```
$Assumptions = {s0 \[Element] Reals, s0 > 0};
Module[{a, b, c, d,
  n = 2, no = 2, X, ji = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}},
 {a, b, c, 
   d} = {{{(-2 + s0)/(2 + s0), Sqrt[s0 (4 + s0^2)]/(2 + s0)}, {Sqrt[
     s0 (4 + s0^2)]/(2 + s0), -((2 + 3 s0)/(2 + s0))}}, {{0, 1/Sqrt[
     2 + s0]}, {Sqrt[(2 + s0)/(
     4 + s0^2)], -(2/Sqrt[(((2 + s0) (4 + s0^2))/s0)])}}, {{-4 Sqrt[
      s0/(2 + s0)], -((2 Sqrt[8 + 4 s0 + 2 s0^2 + s0^3])/(
      2 + s0))}, {-2 Sqrt[2 + s0], 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}};
 X = Array[x, {n, n}];
 
 Print[Solve[
    Simplify[
      a.X + X.a\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.b\[ConjugateTranspose]] ==
      ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], Flatten[X]] // Simplify];
 Print[Solve[
    Simplify[X.c\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.d\[ConjugateTranspose]] ==
      ConstantArray[0, {n, no}], Flatten[X]] // Simplify];

(* Checking that solution solves both equations *)
Print[Simplify[(X /. 
  Solve[Simplify[
     a.X + X.a\[ConjugateTranspose] + 
      b.ji.b\[ConjugateTranspose]] == ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], 
   Flatten[X]]) == (X /. 
  Solve[Simplify[
     X.c\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.d\[ConjugateTranspose]] == 
    ConstantArray[0, {n, no}], Flatten[X]])]];
 
 sols = Solve[
   Simplify[
      a.X + X.a\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.b\[ConjugateTranspose]] ==
      ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]
    && Simplify[
      X.c\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.d\[ConjugateTranspose]] == 
     ConstantArray[0, {n, no}], Flatten[X]]]
```

The output is:

```
{{x[1,1]->-(1/(4+2 s0)),x[1,2]->Sqrt[s0/(4+s0^2)]/(2+s0),x[2,1]->s0/((2+s0) Sqrt[s0 (4+s0^2)]),x[2,2]->1/(4+2 s0)}}
{{x[1,1]->-(1/(4+2 s0)),x[1,2]->Sqrt[s0/(4+s0^2)]/(2+s0),x[2,1]->1/Sqrt[((2+s0)^2 (4+s0^2))/s0],x[2,2]->1/(4+2 s0)}}
True
{}
```

Note that the returned results for the first two `Print` statements (solving them separately) solve both equations, so why isn't `Solve` working?

Comment: If you use `Reduce` instead of `Solve` you get this: `The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) ... A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.`

Comment: There is a generic solution: 
$$ X= (AB J D^\dagger-BJB^\dagger C^\dagger)(A^\dagger C^\dagger)^{-1}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Method->Reduce` you get the result as [`ConditionalExpressions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html).

```
Solve[Simplify[
    a.X + X.a\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.b\[ConjugateTranspose]] == 
   ConstantArray[0, {n, n}] && 
  Simplify[X.c\[ConjugateTranspose] + b.ji.d\[ConjugateTranspose]] == 
   ConstantArray[0, {n, no}], Flatten[X], Method -> Reduce]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can reformulate the problem as a single equation

$$AXC^\dagger + XA^\dagger C^\dagger + BJB^\dagger C^\dagger = 0,\ \ AX C^\dagger + AB J D^\dagger = 0$$

$$ XA^\dagger C^\dagger + BJB^\dagger C^\dagger -AB J D^\dagger= 0$$

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[X.a\[ConjugateTranspose].c\[ConjugateTranspose] + 
    b.ji.b\[ConjugateTranspose].c\[ConjugateTranspose] - 
    a.b.ji.d\[ConjugateTranspose] == ConstantArray[0, {n, n}], 
  Flatten[X]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your reformulation as a single equation is the way I will go! Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you! I still wonder why this is an issue in the first place though

Comment: According to the documentation: "[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed." I did not look deep to work out why the conditions are needed.

Comment: But why do you use `Solve` for a linear equation?

Comment: This code has been running for a long time and cannot give results (MMA v13.0). I wonder if the code is incomplete? Could you give the complete code? Thanks!@Suba Thomas